# Firebase (FCM) message token lost after deleting and reinstalling app in dev mode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was sending push notifications normally, then I needed to delete the app and re install, after that the FCM token was re-generated but when I send a message to this particular device it never gets on the device, the response goes ok, but it never delivers, so I need help with 2 things:

1) how do I refresh, revoke or regenerate FCM tokens.
2) Is there a way to look at some sort of FCM logs, queue or is there any way to debug my FCM service around lost tokens and stale messages?

Comment: Are you using the new token to send to the device? Also could you add the request that you are using to send the message?

Comment: Maybe our problem is related somehow. I know your question is about iOS devices but maybe the problem is more general than it looks, could it be related to the Firebase? [Here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355983/firebase-messaging-not-working-with-android-2-3-6?noredirect=1#comment66070899_39355983)