# Firebase Messaging not working with Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the firebase messaging to send push notifications. I've tested using a device running Android version 4.1.2 with Google Play Services installed (version 3.2.25) and it works, the `onMessageReceived` is called correctly. But when I try to test using a device running Android 2.3.6 and the last Google Play Services (had to install it) the message never arrives even if the Firebase Web UI says that it was sent successfully.

So, why does it work with the newer Android running with an older Google Play Services even if the docs says to use the 9.4.0 version and why it doesn't work in the other scenario.

**Build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sipas"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW--I was able to receive notifications sent from the Firebase console on an old device running 2.3.6 with Play Services 9.4.52.  I build my test app using Firebase 9.4.0.  My initial attempts failed because the phone has a very old version of Play Services.  What version of Play Services are you using?

Comment: I've installed the last version. Maybe it is incompatible with my device, but I believe that is not case because after I installed it the getToken method started to return the token.

Comment: So you are getting a token but not receiving messages? Could you add to your question the gradle dependencies you are using in the non working case. FCM should work from SDK 9. So 2.3.6 should not be the issue.

Comment: @ArthurThompson sorry for the delay. I've updated the question. The gradle is the same for both the working and the non working case.

Comment: @ArthurThompson, yes, I can get a token but the `onMessageReceived` is never called.

Comment: Hi @ArielMoraes it is recommended that you use either FCM or GCM, using both can result in some unexpected behaviour. Could you try using only FCM?

Comment: @ArthurThompson no joy, even if I remove the dependency play-services-gcm. The problem is that by using the library PriorityJobQueue I can't generate an APK with proguard on because it hold some references to the play-services-gcm, that's why I have this dependency.

Comment: @ArielMoraes If GCM is a hard dependency for you then you should remove FCM and use GCM only. Could you try removing FCM and see if it works as expected?

Comment: @ArthurThompson it does not work even if I remove the GCM dependency. I will try to create a new project from scratch and add just the stuff needed as the docs says.

Comment: @ArthurThompson I've created a new project, added just the FCM dependency and still, the same problem. Now the only reference that I have is to the FCM.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I've installed the Play Service, BUT the Play Store was not updated. The phone had the old Android Market, after I added an user account it upgraded and all the notifications arrived. My problem now is: in production we have a lot of devices like this one, adding an user account to each one is not feasible, how can we overcome this?

Comment: Firebase depends on Google Play services, Google Play services is delivered by the Play Store. So a device must have the Play Store installed to get the latest versions of Google Play services.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,try removing compiled 'com.google.gms:google-services:9.4.0' from build.gradle,and my push notifications work very fine on every phone !

Comment: The only line matching what you've said is this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` and the docs says it is necessary: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)